# Server 2012 Remote Desktop Services how to see collections in list that expands off bottom of screen?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, remoteapp

In Server Manager > Remote Desktop Services I have a large list of collections.  The list is already so long that it goes off the bottom of the screen and unfortunately it is only going to keep growing.

I cannot find any way to scroll the list of collections so that I can see the ones that are not currently on screen, does anyone know a way to do this?

I can select one of the visible collections then use the down arrow followed by Return repeatedly to select off-screen items and display the details in the right-hand pane but this is going to become increasingly more tedious as we add more collections.

There isn't any way to do what we need to do without having a large number of collections so that isn't an option.

The practical issue at the moment is that we need to publish or unpublish remote apps in a specific collection so if there is another way to do this I would accept that as a solution.